# Is there a way to avoid a specific road or coordinate in Google Directions?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-directions-api

The API has a parameter for waypoints in order for The API to calculate the route ang pass through the specified waypoint/s. Is there any way where I could give the waypoints to avoid instead of waypoints to pass through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't (currently) implemented. There is an open feature request: [Issue 214: Ability to influence Directions (e.g. "avoid" / "roadblock")](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214).

Comment: Is it still not possible to use this feature?

Comment: What does the issue say?