# Avoid specific point in android map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an issue with android Google Maps. I want find route between two locations but avoid specific points which given in input.

Can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific feature of this kind yet. According to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272322/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-a-specific-road-or-coordinate-in-google-directions), this is a feature request for the Maps API.

However,I can suggest possible alternatives like Using [Waypoints in Routes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints).

**Note: sample was done in Javascript**

In this [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/py98y155/2/), you have 3 markers A, B & C.
A = origin, B = route, C = destination.

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
```

Let's say the initial point of B is blocked, drag it to other streets/points in the map (zoom-in to see other routes) and you have your alternative route. You can read more of waypoints in the [DirectionService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) guide.